# Samsung A6+ correspond to what (comparing with BrowserStack) and css media queries?

Tags: android, css, browserstack

So far I have only written CSS statements for iOS devices. For test purposes I bought a Samsung device (A6+) and found that some of my designs look horrible.

So far I've only tested other devices with BrowserStack, but since someone wrote me that a design that looks good with BrowserStack doesn't look good at all (far too small fonts, elements outside the viewport, etc.), I decided to buy a Samsung smartphone.

Unfortunately, my device does not appear in the BrowserStack (no model with 'A'). If I compare the external appearance of the device with the listed ones, it looks most like a Samsung 8A. Could it be? How do I find the equivalent?

Once I know which equivalent I can look up, how do I address this device with css, i.e. how do I write the media query for this device?

PS: the ios installed is Android 8.0.0 / Samsung Experience-Version 9.0

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

- put more style information (font-sizes) and change the media queries and the wrapper width (% instead of px)
- and e.g. max-width 420 px instead of 380 px
- important also font-size-declaration (in %)

Now everything looks fine :-)